# ng-repeat of array of object on custom directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use ng-repeat on array of below object to repeat my custom directive.

My array looks something like below.

```
var Competitors = [];
Competitors.push({
  key: 1,
  value: {}//Blank object
});
Competitors.push({
  key: 2,
  value: {}//Blank object
});
Competitors.push({
  key: 3,
  value: {}//Blank object
});
```

My custom directive.

```
 module.directive('miChart', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div></div>',
            scope: {
                chartData: "=value",
                chartObj: "=?"
            },            
            replace: true,
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch('chartData', function (value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        return;
                    }

                    $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo = $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo || $element[0];
                    $scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart($scope.chartData);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the code through which i am trying to create multiple chart with my directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in Competitors">
  <mi-chart value="Competitors[key]" chart-obj="Competitors[key]"></mi-chart>
</div>
```

When i debug my code, the directive is not getting exact value and giving Competitors[key] as a value and chart-obj. So it is not replacing the values on ng-repeat.

Can anybody tell what's wrong i am doing and what is the solution to this problem.

Comment: So what is the difference between two attributes `value="Competitors[key]" chart-obj="Competitors[key]"`? You want two bindings to the same object `Competitors[key]`?

Comment: Yes i need same value to be placed for both value and chart-obj attribute.

Comment: Anyway, not clear what your problem is, I tested and your code works fine, data binding is okay.

Comment: I am not able to post image due to my low reputation. But the ng-repeat needs to replace my value with original object in array which it doesn't. I am getting string "Competitors[key]" in value at my directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your html like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="competitor in Competitors track by competitor.key">
   <mi-chart value="competitor" chart-obj="competitor"></mi-chart>
</div>
```

which results in correct binding of the elements as you can see in the code snippet below.
The *track by* component is optional but because you already have a unique key value available it would be wise to use it. It improves performance in case some entries get updated.

However I am not sure if that is what you are looking for.

```js
var module = angular.module('app',[]);

module.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.Competitors = [];
  $scope.Competitors.push({
    key: 1,
    value: {}//Blank object
  });
  $scope.Competitors.push({
    key: 2,
    value: {}//Blank object
  });
  $scope.Competitors.push({
    key: 3,
    value: {}//Blank object
  });
});
module.directive('miChart', function () {
        
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div>-----------<br/>chartData - key: {{chartData.key}} value: {{chartData.value}}<br/>chartObj - key: {{chartObj.key}} value: {{chartObj.value}}</div>',
            scope: {
                chartData: "=value",
                chartObj: "=?"
            },            
            replace: true,
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch('chartData', function (value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    //$scope.chartData.chart.renderTo = $scope.chartData.chart.renderTo || $element[0];
                    //$scope.chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart($scope.chartData);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Entries:
  <div ng-repeat="competitor in Competitors track by competitor.key">
    <mi-chart value="competitor" chart-obj="competitor"></mi-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```